# Matlab: Negative number to the power of n where "n" is bigger than 1 gives an imaginary number

Tags: matlab

I am running a matlab code in order to solve a matrix in an iterative way, I am trying to solve x=A\b in every iteration until x --> 0 by changing A and b, in the first 3 iterations work fine until I reach a point where I start getting imaginary numbers in my solution.

Here is my code:
Q,H,n,R are predefined variables.

```
while(eps > 10^-6)
    i=1;j=1;

    while(i<11)

        A11(i,j) = 1.852*R(i)*(abs(Q(i)))^(n-1);
        i=i+1;
        j=j+1;
    end
    A11(11,11) = 2*R(11)*abs(Q(11));

    %calculate -dE & dq
    dE = [200-H(1)-R(1)*Q(1)^1.852
        H(1)-H(2)- R(2)*Q(2)^1.852
        H(1)-H(3)-R(3)*Q(3)^1.852
        H(2)-H(7)-R(4)*Q(4)^1.852
        H(6)-H(5)-R(5)*Q(5)^1.852
        H(7)-H(4)-R(6)*Q(6)^1.852
        H(6)-H(7)-R(7)*(Q(7))^1.852
        H(5)-H(4)-R(8)*Q(8)^1.852
        H(3)-H(2)-R(9)*Q(9)^1.852
        H(3)-H(4)-R(10)*Q(10)^1.852
        0-H(3)+240- R(11)*Q(11)];
    dq = [-Q(1)+Q(2)+Q(3)
        -Q(2)-Q(9)+Q(4)+4
        -Q(11)+Q(9)+Q(10)+6
        -Q(10)-Q(6)-Q(8)+5
        -Q(5)+Q(8)+5
        -Q(3)+Q(7)+Q(5)+5
        -Q(4)-Q(7)+Q(6)+3];


    %formulate the full set of equations
    zero=zeros(nn,nn);
    b=[dE;dq];
    upA = [A11,A12];
    downA=[A21,zero];
    A= [upA;downA];
    %solve the equations (x=A\b)

    x = A\b;
    %update Q and H
    i=1;j=1;
    while (i<8 && j<12)
        H(i)= x(11+i)+ H(i);
        Q(j)= x(j)+ Q(j);
        i=i+1;
        j=j+1;
    end
    %check stopping criteria
    j=1;sumeps=0;
    while (j<12)
        sumeps=sumeps+x(j);
        j=j+1;
    end
    epscal = sumeps/12;

    eps=abs(epscal)

end
```

I realized that i start getting problems when one of the values of vector Q turns negative, and when that value is raised to the power of 1.852 (while calculating dE) it gives an imaginary number!!

Maybe someone knows whre

Comment: See this question on the math SE site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. (-1)^N has an imaginary component whenever N has a fractional component.

Most obviously, (-1)^0.5 is just `i`.

Comment: Someone has to retake some math courses here ... Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

It's not the fact hat the power is bigger than 1, it's the fact that the power is not an integer (i.e. `X^2, X^3, ...`). Imagine `X^0.5` which equals `sqrt(X)`. Obviously that yields an imaginary number for negative values of X.